# Increase resolution of kinect rgb camera on ros

Tags: kinect, resolution, ros

i am doing a project using deep learning and for this i need to take pictures from the kinect and evaluate them. My problem is the resolution of the pictures are 640x860. Due to this i wanted to know if ros freekinect or some library can increase the resolution given a yaml file or something like that? Thank you guys and sorry for the english

Answer (score 1):

Im currently working on a project with Kinect one sensor and the camera resolution is 1920x1080.
if i am not wrong you are currently using the old xbox 360 kinect from what i see here.
[image]

I have not heard of libraries that can increase resolutiono yet(this does not mean it do not exist)
But my suggestion is to use the latest hardware found in [Microsoft Store here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/store/d/kinect-sensor-for-xbox-one/91HQ5578VKSC/4GB4?s_kwcid=AL!4249!3!191903168059!!!g!301318994389!&WT.mc_id=sg_datafeed_pla_google_pointitsem_xbox&ef_id=V5q10AAAACSnLUP0:20170526043020:s). It cost about $150.

Cheers!